# Google cloud ml speech - lost id of asynchronous operation

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-ml

I ran asynchronous speech to text operation, but I lost the operation ID. I can see that the operation ran in my quota graphs, but I can't find its ID anywhere. Is there any way of recovering that ID or getting the operation result?
Or do I have to run the operation again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make the request again, as there's no logging of these operations.